# ePub Reader Application using Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am trying to create an ePub reader application using Phonegap. 
I tried to find it on google but i didn't find any thing related to ePub reader.Please help me.

Comment: There is already something like this.... https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/issues/101

Comment: I tried it but it is reading some html files from reader/mobi-dick directory. can you please tell me how to read .epub file by this project.

Comment: I don't know whether I can help you on that one directly. But I have a tip for you to get help. See when you are asking a question on stackoverflow be specific and tell them what you have done and where exactly you are stuck at. And before that you should also search if a similar question exists... If it is similar but doesnt work for you. When writing a new question mention  it that you tried that answer too. Also have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask Hope I helped you :)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion related to read epub file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Readium JS epub viewer library
https://github.com/readium/readium-js
https://github.com/readium/readium-js-viewer

With this library you can create Java Script epub reader and then use Phonegap to bundle it into mobile app. 
The other option would be to host reader on server and use Phonegap only to provide application to access it. Cloud Reader type of access.

Comment: To improve this answer I would suggest that you extract useful parts from the link into your answers. The perception is that link only answers aren't that useful.